# Unknown column 'trip' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, database

Not sure why it gives me an error of an unknown column of trip when trip is a table. From what I am aware the argument in the left and right of left outer join should be tables not columns. So why does this give an column error and how can I fix this error?

```
SELECT equipment.EquipID, equipment.EquipmentName, COUNT(trip) AS "NumTrips"
FROM equipment LEFT OUTER JOIN trip
ON equipment.EquipID = trip.EquipID;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `count()` function expects a field name or * as parameter. Since you supplied `trip` as a parameter, mysql is looking for a field called `trip`, hence the error message.

Solution: provide the desired field from `trip` table you would like to count, or `trip.*` as parameter to the `count()` function.

Comment: I usually use the PK or the FK which is used for the join. Since they both are part of the FK index, no table lookup is needed.